# Passing parameters to INSERT ..ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487179/correct-insert-on-duplicate-key-syntax)

Which is the correct syntax to pass parameters to INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in c# ?
I tried like this

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(ID,number,color) VALUES (@r,@c,@e)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table (number) VALUES (@c,@e) ", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", a_name)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", a_color)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But this syntax is not correct. Any ideas?

Comment: -1 For asking the same question twice in a row.

Comment: @Johan didn't realize this was a duplicate. Voted to close it too.

Comment: @Icarus, the other question had a very obscure title _(before the edit)_ , so it has hard to match them using just the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table(ID,number) VALUES (@r,@c) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = @c
```

Therefore you should have something like:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table(ID,number) VALUES (@r,@c) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = @c ", conn);
```

Comment: why number? what if i had to deal with a string?

Comment: @redfrogsbinary `number` is your column name, no?  You listed it in your insert statement: `insert into table(ID,number)....`

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = @c , color = @e would be correct?

Comment: @redfrogsbinary Yes, it should be.